# What are the strategies for catching unboxing and autoboxing issues at compile time?

Tags: java

I'm editing this question to differentiate it from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407), and to remove the dreaded "why?"

If I have a java method that returns the java object `Integer`, the java compiler allow me to assign that to a primitive `int`.  This seems to be asking for runtime trouble.  ie. what if Integer is null?

```
public class SomeClass {
    private Integer someIntegerObject;

    public Integer getSomeIntegerObject() {
        return this.someIntegerObject;
    }
}

SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
//much later...
int someIntegerPrimative = someClass.someIntegerObject();
```

This will blow up at runtime if `someIntegerObject` was set to null at all, but it seems like something that could easily be caught at compile time.

This functionality is called "unboxing" and its opposite is "auto-boxing".  It is intended to save the developer time and readability from unboxing each of these manually.

The question is: what are the best strategies for catching potential issues here at compile-time?

Comment: Search the internet for "Java autoboxing"

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: The answer to your "what if" is that you get an exception.  Auto unboxing is nothing but a shorthand to make your code clearer to the reader.

Comment: Plus one for discovering what I think is one of the major flaws in Java. Wait until you discover the pre-caching of -128 to +127. The blow-up you get if you attempt to convert a null to an `int` is a NullPointerException which is an *unchecked* exception to make matters even worse. With a sign of relief, I'm back to C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we use autoboxing and unboxing in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407/why-do-we-use-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java)

Comment: @Bathsheba interesting how you define a major flaw.  How is this worse than using the long hand `Integer.intValue()`

Comment: Major flaw number 2.

Comment: @Bathsheba I agree that `NullPointerExceptions` are a major flaw in general. But if you're going to say "back to c++" then I will leave you with the words `segmentation fault` and be done with it.

Comment: How could you? Now we have std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr ;-)

Comment: Easily. I still have to debug code which has C style pointers through it.

Comment: And as my parting remark, you must admit that type erasure was a really bad idea !

Comment: for "why" questions, read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/217324

Comment: @NathanHughes- I've edited the question to remove the "why", putting the focus on concrete solutions for catching these issues at compile-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JRE / Compiler does something called Auto Unboxing - which is designed to save developer time when it comes to activities like this.

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Edit: you might want to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992077/unboxing-a-null-boxed-object-throws-unexpected-nullpointerexception) re your point on null objects - looks like a runtime error NullPointerException will be thrown, but you can setup most IDE's to warn about auto unboxing at compile time to help you either:

a) Make sure you have the right exception handling or;

b) Make sure you are not relying on the behaviour at all (always calling the method to get the primitive value)

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the "why?" and put the focus on compile-time solutions.  Since your answer offers those, I will choose this as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The concept your talking about is *Auto-unboxing*.
The value of a type wrapper (here *Integer*) is automatically extracted whenever it is needed. Basically auto-unboxing removes the tedium of manually boxing and unboxing values. It is mostly important to **Generics**, which operate only on objects. This feature makes working with **Collections Framework** much easier. And we can always catch a *NullPointerException*. Java provides pretty good exceptional handling mechanism. Let's use it even if tiniest possibility of exceptions exist.